# Pytables select rows based on a list of matched column values

Tags: python, hdf5, pytables

I want to select in a HDF5 file by a column matching a discrete list of values. However, supposedly my query contains a few dozens of values and possibly several different key columns, so I don't want to use an in-kernel super long query such as:

```
((key1=="value1")|(key1=="value2")) & ((key2=="value3")|(key1=="value4"))
```

However, it must still be done in kernel somehow, for speed considerations (I am also indexing columns and keeping my huge table sorted). Here is some helper code, where I match one single value:

```
import string
import random
import tables as pt


class KeyValue(pt.IsDescription):
    key = pt.StringCol(itemsize=30, dflt=" ", pos=0)
    value = pt.UInt16Col(dflt=0, pos=1)


file = pt.open_file("test.hdf5", "w", title=title)
m = file.create_table("/", "test", KeyValue)

for j in range(20):
    values = []
    for i in range(100000):
        key = "".join(random.sample(string.ascii_uppercase, 5))
        value = random.randint(0, 1000000)
        values.append((key, value))
    m.append(values)

rows = file.root.test.read_where('key == b"AAAA"')
file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a list of the values you want to select, you can generate the query string by using string concatenation:

```
"&".join(["(key={0})".format(value) for value in values])
```